# slideDown works, but when I change to slideUp, it stops working

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

I have 2 small divs, side by side in a bigger div, display flex. I want one of the small divs to appear by sliding up, and the other by sliding down. They both work fine when sliding down, but when I change one to slide up, it doesn't show the div.

I've tried position:relative, also in jQuery using the hide() and show() functions instead of just display: none in my css. But I know that the display:none in css works fine with the sliding down, so I just Don't get it!

```
   <div class="nousEtMission">
        <div id="quiSommesNous"> TEST 1
        </div>
        <div id="mission"> TEST 2
        </div>
    </div>

<script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#header").fadeIn(1500);
        $("#quiSommesNous").slideUp(3000);
        $("#mission").slideDown(3000);
</script>

.nousEtMission{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    height: 30vh;
}

#quiSommesNous{
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(123, 216, 35);
    width: 50%;
}

#mission{
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(26, 207, 132);
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: SlideUp only hides it does not show. Best to consult the jquery documentation http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Comment: You might want to familiarize yourself with css transitions to get your desired effect

Comment: As Funk Doc mentioned the slideUp is used to hide the element while sliding in up direction. You cannot reveal an element using slideUp. Look into Jquery animate or CSS transitions

Comment: Oh... that'd explain it! It's a shame, I'm trying to use jQuery as much as possible just to learn it, remember the syntax etc. Oh, well, I'll go the CSS route. Thank you both.